# Apache Zeppelin server https redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, http-redirect, apache-zeppelin

I've successfully set up Zeppelin with SSL enabled. Now https works but http doesn't. Is there a way I can set up a redirect rule that channels http traffic to https?  Should I use `.htaccess` or something similar?

Not quite familiar with the zeppelin server configs, thanks a lot!

Comment: which version of Zeppelin do you use?

Comment: @KhalidHuseynov, Version 0.7.0

Comment: I'm trying to get Zeppelin working with a self-signed cert, how did you get your setup to work?